# How does public and primary keys look like in rsa c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, bouncycastle

I am trying to use Asymmetric key algorithm rsa to secure my APIs.

suppose i create a Key pair for a user Who is using my APIs

as

```
RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();     

string PublicKey = RSA.ToXmlString(false);    

string PrivateKey =  RSA.ToXmlString(true);
```

now my private key look like

```
 <RSAKeyValue>  
    <Modulus>tMvvUeHhggKAVex8JzYKXYQ32HVmr05PdtT1KV3kTkKE26jO/9IVmg+bWwxR1vuMzmY7spwguSJQsnjutJXamH0 mblNgYHmWwhyhJMSTtnZp57VDNNedjCFQnLOn211yk/PpCQHEiDDvt84hnmcdXNBlfZfkQzQ+UO/elhP5NH0=</Modulus>  
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>  
    <P>22SSx3JpSqYVUWuxiSKwmh/8RDDcgDvq8l+4dMlQ/F+BJhthTQ3UJGupWaxiJyXX95AYAJIJJvWVvmvI7tqbxw==</P><Q>0va2WFy0oUwX4eJtZElRbot9TOrwGcqI64rMAYjvxl/mayCRXf0ypwKofKWOsmjK/pX0xWaqnFWB/NdLFt4Fmw==</Q><DP>VbIYPz2qcRUkmJQnWbiqINnDkONBDfnZkOjgxQVp09p+OONTA2UWa09+a9+Qy1fV3wZyya5BUu10m1fAucO8Ow==</DP>  
    <DQ>Lm8hOZfGJk6SXySwgUdmBhfrz3dSu8qJkpatSpUyeY54MBIuDOsDMCF0pmLmYryQGbM1+hEb8mcbwmQ84d6iiw==</DQ>  
    <InverseQ>L67OLIIK+M3OF1nxSHTjZ+Kv/hwOHJPvdHHSuh9VEmw93kPGn6Qt6GudEreFb6xlFsuR6UM19LUIweapgaUagQ==</InverseQ>  
    <D>YbaGlZ6bHoTzj3zMbPTMDVbUR+zLnpuYXwUhq0XPimxxGbbWiXSlsCoXMNIruSEjLLocMaAoH2bobkzl1jvXdAI30NdZ/rpG5SRl dpaeIundLfHkSnZfHwHuP9OGXJSXmbmLCrO8dq7BjLauS4JiTRgjiXoq8c995MEF+vhw9hE=</D>  
</RSAKeyValue>
```

And this is my public key

```
 <RSAKeyValue>  
    <Modulus>lF1Yof6FXaY9M/StHwPC1voW5K5JOqSu8BXndS4WH06L9mOfrNI9Et0cRaHjiYd2bQNFZB9+ AZmN4ODc36DgVPqQqYY2tbH+9UY0hcdi+WnDuUZe7sgvWKfGwBKTcy7g8uUAzpTWEP1W0FqeMunmXljD8Iouoqp5oHtTW1GHIlE=</Modulus>  
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>  
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Now my doubt is here  Private key string also contain  public key

what part of  private or public key string should i send to user as it is in

```
XmlFormat
```

and there are multiple tags like `modulus ,D,Q` in the `string` what is actually a `key` in the string which i send to a user as his `public` , `pvt keys`
as my  user will be on android platform
will he be able to use those keys in `xml format` ?

like in `c#` when we have to use keys

i do             `rsa.FromXmlString(Key);`
where `public` or `private  key` is in `XmlFormat` 
Can that user will able to do this on `android` as well

Comment: "what part of private or public key string should i send to user" - we don't know since you haven't established what the user is intended to *do* with the key. If, however, it turns out that their key usage requires them to use the private key, I'd seriously question *why your service is generating these keys in the first place*.

Comment: there is a requirement to generate these keys to system end

Comment: user will use those keys to decrypt in coming and encrypt  out going message

Comment: Then it sounds like what you really need are symmetric keys/crypto, not asymmetric, because you're saying that both ends of the connection need to be able to encrypt and decrypt?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest given both this and your previous question that you visit the [crypto stack exchange site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) and describe the *design* of your system (not your problems with implementing) in terms of the protocol - who the parties are, what communication there is between the parties and how cypto is employed at each stage, and then ask them to fix it. You may want to consider asking a meta question there first to see if it's on topic but I think it should be.

Comment: No @Damien_The_Unbeliever only that user will use those keys i accidentally type in the above comment but he will encrypt by the systems Public key not by any of his keys